# How to merge docx documents in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, docx

I have to merge docx documents in nodejs.
I know docx-merger, but it has problems.

It causes problems when there is a header.
and then, I want to merge into the next line, not the next page.

Is there a related library or code?.

I think it's impossible in NodeJs , so considering using Spire in Java api server.
but, I want to avoid make a api server.

Is there any way Nodejs can handle it?

Answer (score 1):

[docx-merger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-merger) seems fine to me,

I also using this package in react, which mean its inside the browser,

```
import DocxMerger from "docx-merger"
let file = [] // this should be array of docx, should be (ArrayBuffer or UInt8Array) only if its from browser
// if its node u can use fs.readFileSync
// if u get the files from input, u need to convert it to blob and then convert it to ArrayBuffer

let options = {}
const result = new DocxMerger(options, file);

result.save("blob", data => {
   // u can do anything with the data here
})
```